# Entry in one column mustn't exist in all the entries of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a task to write a query that select all of the files, which are NOT a parent to any other file. I have a table 'Files' that have columns 'Id' and 'ParentId'.

This is my query, but it doesn't work correctly, because query selects rows that have different 'Id' and 'ParentId'

```
SELECT Id, [Name], CONCAT(Size, 'KB') AS Size FROM Files
WHERE Id <> ParentId
ORDER BY Id, [Name], Size DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select all of the files, which are NOT a parent to any other file

Use `not exist`:

```
select f.*
from files f
where not exists(select 1 from files f1 where f1.parentid = f.id)
```